# CEF class CefBrowserSettings - field description

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

Please tell me what I can't figure out, and where in the official documentation can I see the description of fields or methods of the CefBrowserSettings class?

The official documentation only has a blank page: [https://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects /(default)/CefBrowserSettings.html](https://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects%20/(default)/CefBrowserSettings.html)

Answer (score 0):

CEF is an [open source project](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/Home). You can check its source code and get the required documentation or API specification.

CefBrowserSettings is not a class. It's defined like that:

```
///
// Class representing browser initialization settings.
///
typedef CefStructBase<CefBrowserSettingsTraits> CefBrowserSettings;
```

See the corresponding [source code](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/3d1bbaf54f24d664f00bad0cfd38217d5c553383/include/internal/cef_types_wrappers.h?at=master#lines-728).